# How to execute javascript code after htmx makes an ajax request?

Tags: django, htmx

Im currently building a website with django and htmx and i like the combination so far.  Lets say I use an htmx attribute on a button to replace a div in the DOM with another div that is supposed to contain a wysiwyg editor. Now the wysiwyg editor has to be initialized with javascript. How do I do this? Can I just return the script tag under the editor div that is being requested with htmx? Wouldnt that be also a little ugly or bad practice because youd have script tags in the middle of the html body? Whats the best way of solving this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out HTMX after request event.

It should look something like this

```js
htmx.on('htmx:afterRequest', (evt) => {
  // check which element triggered the htmx request. If it's the one you want call the function you need
//you have to add htmx: before the event ex: 'htmx:afterRequest'
})
```

Answer (score 15):

**Short Answer**

To run specific code after an HTMX request, you need to be listening for the `htmx:afterRequest` event.

Whether it's just a single `htmx:afterRequest` event that you are trying to listen to *(or if you have code that should run after **all** htmx requests)*, you can use the below event listener to run your code after any HTMX request is completed:

```js
document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', function(evt) {
    // Put the JS code that you want to execute here
});
```

---

**Long Answer**

If you want it to run after a specific event only, you need access to the `evt` object associated with the event, to which you should refer to the official docs [here](https://htmx.org/docs/#events) in full. However I have put some simple examples below to demonstrate what this can look like.

```js
document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', function(evt) {
    if(evt.detail.xhr.status == 404){
        /* Notify the user of a 404 Not Found response */
        return alert("Error: Could Not Find Resource");
    } 
    if (evt.detail.successful != true) {
        /* Notify of an unexpected error, & print error to console */
        alert("Unexpected Error");
        return console.error(evt);
    }
    if (evt.detail.target.id == 'info-div') {
        /* Execute code on the target of the HTMX request, which will
        be either the hx-target attribute if set, or the triggering 
        element itself if not set. */
        let infoDiv = document.getElementById('info-div');
        infoDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';  // black background
        infoDiv.style.color = '#FFFFFF';  // white text
    }
});
```

For a full list of HTMX events you can listen to *(e.g. `htmx:configRequest`  to modify the HTMX AJAX request before it is sent)* check out the official reference [here](https://htmx.org/reference/#events).

As to the question of where to put this in your code, the only technical necessity is to be listening for the event before the event triggers: i.e. do not send this code in your response, already have it in your page beforehand. Then where to put stylistically is essentially a matter of preference. In a Django + HTMX stack, it would be perfectly valid to either include this as a `script` tag within the template itself, or put it inside a static js file and link to it. Just make sure the HTMX library is loaded before this executes, and you have accounted for `csrf` issues appropriately.

Comment: This should have been accepted answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: The event listener takes an event as its argument. So right there in the event handler function you can examine the triggering event and take appropriate action.

Comment: @VinaySajip yes you're absolutely right, I will edit the code now to reflect that, many thanks

Comment: Also, it might be better to use the `htmx:afterSettle` event. In the case of both `htmx:afterRequest` and `htmx:afterSwap` I found that the DOM wasn't completely replaced at the time the JS code ran. With `htmx:afterSettle` the replacement seems to be there reliably :-)

Comment: If your favorite search engine brought you here, I confirm that `htmx:afterSettle` is likely to be what you're looking for! See the doc [here](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:afterSettle)

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to write JavaScript for this (except the script to run), which is one of the main points of using HTMX.

`hx-on` attribute (mentioned first by cyberfly), https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-on/

```html
<button hx-get="/info" hx-on::after-request="alert('Done making a request!')">
    Get Info!
</button>
```

you can also replace `hx-on::after-request` with `hx-on:htmx:after-request`
(Take note of the double colon `::` without htmx)

You can also handle multiple events:

```html
<button hx-get="/info"
        hx-on::before-request="alert('Making a request!')"
        hx-on::after-request="alert('Done making a request!')">
    Get Info!
</button>
```

You can also use `hx-on` with other event such as click. I.e. `hx-on:click`

Answer (score 1):

The HTMX *after request* event is triggered after ***all*** the requests.

We then have to check the event.target and trigger a function or not depending on the current target. It's not really relevant for the optimization.

I haven't found a built-in solution to execute a script only after a specific request. If anyone has a solution with sample code I'm interested.

On the other hand, I don't see any problem with integrating a `<script />` tag into the response sent back by the server. It works like a charm, it's simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

General example with `htmx:before-request` and `htmx:after-request`

```
// form.html
<button
  hx-post="/api/v1/title"
  hx-on:htmx:before-request="emptyDiv('#titles_container')"
  hx-on:htmx:after-request="doSomething()"
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary"
>
  Generate Title
</button>
```

```
// form.js

window.emptyDiv = function emptyDiv(id) {
  $(id).empty();
};

window.doSomething = function doSomething() {
  console.log('do something');
};
```